# How to read integers from System.in with BufferedReader?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I want to take input as 1 to 10 numbers using BufferedReader.
For that i am using a loop.
ERROR is : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
The code is :

```
import java.io.*;
class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int input=0;
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
             input = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that mean you try to convert empty string to number

Comment: Do you really enter a number or just press Enter?

Comment: Just Use A `Scanner`

Comment: Enter the number 1 by one i.e, Entering 1 then pressing enter then 2.

Comment: I am bit new to BufferedReader,I am entering numbers not just Enter.

Comment: @radiance that's not possible if you enter a number that error not occurs

Comment: @getlost please try the code and let me know .Thanks

Comment: @radiance yes your code work for me ..do you enter spaces with number like 2  .

Comment: The first number i type is 1 then i press enter then type 2 then press enter and get this error

Comment: i enter 1 and enter then 2 then enter ..no errors

Comment: @getlost i am using a IDE JCreator for it . Can it be causing error ?

Comment: i don't think.but you can easily run this in cmd and check..

Comment: @getlost thankyou for your help. I ran it directly in cmd and got the output . Though no idea why the JCreator is throwing such an Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Thankyou for all the help.
I was using JCreator IDE and it was causing the problem.
Running the program directly on cmd caused no problem.
The program caused no errors while running on other IDEs as well.
Thankyou.